# Simulate group by in mdx

Tags: mdx, olap

I have a Fact Table That has the list of all courses that every employee in the company has been passed.

FactPassedCourse: (CourseKey, EmployeeKey, DateKey)

DimEmployee: (EmployeeKey)

DimCourse: (CourseKey)

### DimEmployee

Emp1 , Emp2

### DimCourse

Course1, Course2, Course3, Course4, Course5

```
FactPassedCourse
-----------------------------------------
(Emp1, Course1, DateKey1)
(Emp1, Course2, DateKey2)
(Emp1, Course2, DateKey3)
(Emp1, Course3, DateKey3)
(Emp1, Course4, DateKey3)
(Emp2, Course4, DateKey1)
(Emp2, Course5, DateKey5)
```

DimEmployee & DimCourse Has Regular Relationship With FactPassedCourse in my Cube.

I want to get the count of Employees based on every courses but if an employee passed a special course(like Course2) more than once, the employee must be counted just one time I mean this result I want:

MDX result:

```
(Coursename: Course1    Employee_Count: 1)
(Coursename: Course2    Employee_Count: 1:because ONE employee passed this course two times)
(Coursename: Course3    Employee_Count: 1)
(Coursename: Course4    Employee_Count: 2: because two different employees passed this course)
(Coursename: Course5    Employee_Count: 1)
```

In order to get this result I wrote this mdx query and this return the correct result but the performance of this query is very slow.

```
With 
  Member [measures].[Employee_Count] as 
     Count(
        Filter(
          [DimEmployee].EmployeeKey].members-[DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey].[All]),
          [measures].[FactPassedCourseCount]>0)
        )
  Set [Course_Set] as 
     Filter(
       ([DimCourse].[CourseKey].members–[DimCourse].CourseKey].[All]),
        [measures].[FactPassedCourseCount] > 0
     )
Select 
   [measures].[Employee_Count] on 0
 , [Course_Set] on 1 
From MyCube
```

This Query Result is:

```
(Coursename: Course1    Employee_Count: 1)
(Coursename: Course2    Employee_Count)
(Coursename: Course3    Employee_Count: 1)
(Coursename: Course4    Employee_Count)
(Coursename: Course5    Employee_Count: 1)
```

is there a better way to write this mdx query that have fast performance?

Comment: why do you subtract the `[All]` member like you do, on two occassions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this quicker?

```
With 
  Member [measures].[Employee_Count] as 
     Count(
        EXISTING 
           NONEMPTY(
             [DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey].[EmployeeKey]
            ,[measures].[FactPassedCourseCount]
           )
        )
Select 
   [measures].[Employee_Count] on 0
 , NONEMPTY(
      [DimCourse].[CourseKey].[CourseKey]
     ,[measures].[FactPassedCourseCount]
   ) on 1 
From [MyCube];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is the mdx query that I want.

Comment: And Another Question is If I want to filter data base on a value in FactPassedCourseCount, what should I do? because when I use Filter function the performance will be awful.

Comment: @Nazanin if you just want to get rid of null/0 values then always use `NonEmpty` - performance is better - if you want to filter on a condition like `>100` then you have no choice but to use `Filter`

Comment: With 
  Member [measures].[Employee_Count] as 
     Count(
        EXISTING 
           NONEMPTY(
                    ( [DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey].[EmployeeKey],[measures].[FactPassedCourseCount]),
   [DimDate].[DateKey].&[DateKey1] 
               )
        )
Select 
   [measures].[Employee_Count] on 0
 , NONEMPTY(
      [DimCourse].[CourseKey].[CourseKey]
     ,[measures].[FactPassedCourseCount]
   ) on 1 
From [MyCube];

Comment: I've write the query like above. this works fine but the persormance is not as good as your query (about 3 seconds longer than prev query) also nonempty does not remove Zero values.

Comment: according to the brackets in your query the NonEmpty is checking a tuple `(
            [DimEmployee].[EmployeeKey].[EmployeeKey]
           ,[measures].[FactPassedCourseCount]
          )` for emptiness against a date `[DimDate].[DateKey].&[DateKey1]`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the accepted answer -

```
with member [measures].[Employee_Count] AS
NonEmpty
    (
     [DimEmployee].EmployeeKey].[EmployeeKey].members,
     ([DimCourse].[CourseKey].Currentmember, [measures].[FactPassedCourseCount])
    ).Count


Select 
   [measures].[Employee_Count] on 0
 , [Course_Set] on 1 
From MyCube
```

Further, if you want to do filtering based on any value, there is a way to do that without using `filter`.

```
with
member measures.GrtThan5 as
IIF(
    [Measures].[Claim As Of - Count] > 5,
    1,
    NULL
   )
```

The definition would have to change to below -

```
member [measures].[Employee_Count] AS
NonEmpty
    (
     [DimEmployee].EmployeeKey].[EmployeeKey].members,
     ([DimCourse].[CourseKey].Currentmember, [measures].GrtThan5)
    ).Count
```